# Combining jQuery libraries: realistic-typewriter.js and waypoint.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently designing a website for a university project based around the open source project. My website is based around an infinite scroll layout, the idea is for each section to have a terminal that looks like the command line and to have the text print to these screens.

I have implemented realistic-typewriter.js (https://github.com/fardjad/realistic-typewriter.js) for the self-typing text. To have the animations triggered at pre-defined moments (when the user is at that section of the page) I have been told to use waypoint.js (https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints)

Now my problem is implementing the 2 together.

Typewriter.js is implemented something like this.

```
    var typewriter = require('typewriter');
    var twSpan = document.getElementById('typewriter');
    var tw = typewriter(targetDomElement).withAccuracy(90)
                                 .withMinimumSpeed(5)
                                 .withMaximumSpeed(10)
                                 .build();

    tw.clear()
    .type('TEXT GOES IN HERE')

 });
```

What I don't understand here is the syntax of the variables at the start, it seems a bit convulted to my amateur eye.

The tw.clear() line - I assume the tw is the variable and the .clear does what?

Now the waypoint library - I was previously using this fine with the typed.js library, but its functionality was a bit limited and I was advised to move over to realistic-typewriter.js, the code doesn't seem to work in the same way with realistic-typewriter.js.

Here is the example code for waypoint.js from its documentation.

```
   $('.thing').waypoint(function() {
     // i tried to put the above code in here but it doesn't seem to work
   ); offset: '50%'
   });
```

Basically I need to know how to combine waypoint.js and realistic-typewriter.js, but any explanations of the working processes of these would also be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

tw is an object that is accessing the "clear" method, which I am guessing clears out the element so it can type in it.

Also, looks like your waypoints code something is off. Should be something like:

```
$('.thing').waypoint(function() { 
    //code goes here
}, { offset: '50%' });
```

If you place the realistic-typewriter code there it should run it once you've reached that element.